# Exception handling in Python without need for heaps of except statements

Tags: python, pandas

I'm running a try loop that is appending a dataframe. Sometimes appending an element within the df will fail, I don't mind that but I'd like it to just be ignored and continue with everything else within the try loop. I'm currently using `except: pass` but this is meaning that everything else doesn't get done in the try loop.

For example if it fails at `df['putiv'].loc[i]=put.implied_volatility` then everything below that line will be passed where I don't want it to be, I just want `putiv` to be ignored and keep moving on.

code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import wallstreet as ws 
from openpyxl import load_workbook 
import datetime

def day(string_date): 
    return(int(i[0][0]+i[0][1]))

def month(string_date): 
    return(int(i[0][3]+i[0][4]))

def year(string_date): 
    return(int(i[0][6]+i[0][7]+i[0][8]+i[0][9]))

c=ws.Call('AAPL', source='yahoo') 
lst=[(i,j) for i in c.expirations[: 1] for j in c.strikes[25: 30]] 
index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(lst, names=['Expiry', 'Strike']) 


df=pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=['expDate', 'strike', 'callBid', 'callAsk','callPrice', 'iv', 'delta', 'gamma', 'vega', 'theta', 'rho',\
                                      'putBid', 'putAsk', 'putExp', 'putStrike', 'putiv', 'putDelta', 'putGamma', 'putVega', 'putTheta', 'putRho'])  

for i in df.index: 
   # print('d: ', day(i), 'm: ', month(i), 'y: ', year(i)) 

    try: 
        call=ws.Call('AAPL', source='yahoo', d=day(i), m=month(i), y= year(i)) 
        call.set_strike(i[1])
        put=ws.Put('AAPL', source='yahoo', d=day(i), m=month(i), y= year(i))  
        put.set_strike(i[1]) 

        df['expDate'].loc[i]=call.expiration 
        df['strike'].loc[i]=call.strike 
        df['callBid'].loc[i]=call.bid 
        df['callAsk'].loc[i]=call.ask 
        df['iv'].loc[i]=call.implied_volatility()
        df['callPrice'].loc[i]=call.price 
        df['delta'].loc[i]=call.delta() 
        df['gamma'].loc[i]=call.gamma() 
        df['vega'].loc[i]=call.vega() 
        df['theta'].loc[i]=call.theta()
        df['rho'].loc[i]=call.rho()


        df['putExp'].loc[i]=put.expiration 
        df['putStrike'].loc[i]=put.strike 
        df['putBid'].loc[i]=put.bid 
        df['putAsk'].loc[i]=put.ask 
        df['putPrice'].loc[i]=put.price 
        df['putiv'].loc[i]=put.implied_volatility() 
        df['putDelta'].loc[i]=put.delta() 
        df['putGamma'].loc[i]=put.gamma() 
        df['putVega'].loc[i]=put.vega() 
        df['putTheta'].loc[i]=put.theta()
        df['putRho'].loc[i]=put.rho()

    except KeyboardInterrupt: break
    except: 
        print(i, 'error') 
        pass
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping *just that line* (`df['putiv'] = ...`) with `try/except`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general trick here is to translate:

```
df['expDate'].loc[i] = call.expiration
```

into a function call that wraps the try/except block:

```
def set_value(i, col, attr):
    try:
        val = getattr(call, attr)
        # tweak thanks to @cullzie (to ensure it's called if necessary)
        val = val() if callable(val) else val
        df[col].loc[i] = val
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        raise
    except:
        pass
```

So that:

```
df['expDate'].loc[i] = call.expiration 
# becomes
set_value(i, 'expDate', 'expiration')
```

Comment: I totally agree.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes!

Comment: @AndyHayden If you call getattr on **implied_volatility** though you will get something like this: <bound method Call.implied_volatility of <Call object at 0x04115F70>>. I have added an answer which covers all cases: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54454224/6657098)

Comment: @AndyHayden Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following code should do what you want and will account for both an attribute or a method of the put/call object being called. Default return is *None* at the moment but you can handle that as you like.

```
def get_value(obj, attr):
    result = None
    try:
        attribute = getattr(obj, attr) 
        result = attribute() if callable(attribute) else attribute 
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))

    return result
```

Sample usage:

```
    df['iv'].loc[i] = get_value(call, 'implied_volatility')
    df['callPrice'].loc[i] = get_value(call, 'price')
```

Psuedo call class I used for testing it out:

```
class Call(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.price = 100

    def implied_volatility(self):
        return 0.001
```